# Adding a marker on a seaborn lineplot for each observation

Tags: seaborn

I have a simple dataframe that I want to plot with a seaborn/matplotlib:

```
     STA#  RUN# BIB#            COURSE INTER 1  FINISH       DAG
64     22     1   12  STRAIGHT-GLIDING   19,01   19.37  TRENING1
72    148     8   12          COURSE 2   19,08   19.44  TRENING1
74    204    11   12          COURSE 2   19,10   19.47  TRENING1
76    253    14   12          COURSE 2   19,13   19.49  TRENING1
79    186    10   12          COURSE 2   19,13   19.50  TRENING1
294   277    13   12          COURSE 1   18,33   18.68  TRENING2
297   283    14   12          COURSE 1   18,35   18.70  TRENING2
299   165     7   12          COURSE 1   18,37   18.71  TRENING2
300   243    11   12          COURSE 1   18,38   18.73  TRENING2
304   262    12   12          COURSE 1   18,42   18.76  TRENING2
308   102     4   12          COURSE 1   18,44   18.78  TRENING2
```

I am managed to create a lineplot using the following code with seaborn:

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, hue="COURSE", col="DAG", palette="Set2")
g = g.map(sns.lineplot, "RUN#", "FINISH")
g.add_legend()
```

It looks okay but I want a dot for each observation that I have in addition to the line. Any ideas of how I can accomplish this task?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add `marker='o'` to the call to `lineplot`

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, hue="COURSE", col="DAG", palette="Set2")
g = g.map(sns.lineplot, "RUN#", "FINISH", marker='o')
g.add_legend()
```